# Python firebase credentials without json file

Tags: python, firebase

I'm trying to generate an .exe file but I need to add to code firebase_admin credentials. Until now I did it with the local path to .json file but now I need to add this as a dict to avoid the .json file use. I've read several articles about this topic but any of them have clarified this issue for me (I'm not an expert) what changes I've to do in the pasted text of .json file.
The pasted .json file looks like this:

```
cred=credentials.Certificate{
     "type": "######",
     "project_id": "######",
     "private_key_id": "######",
     "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----######-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
     "client_email": "######",
     "client_id": "######",
     "auth_uri": "######",
     "token_uri": "######",
     "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "######",
     "client_x509_cert_url": "######"
}

Thank you in advance
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the opening and closing parenthesis. Reading through [these lines](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/blob/59a22b3ef3263530b1f1b61a3416ef311c24477b/firebase_admin/credentials.py#L81-L86), the expected argument for `credentials.Certificate()` is either a “Path to a certificate file or a dict representing the contents of a certificate”.

So you could pass the dict representing the content of the certificate like this:

```py
cred=credentials.Certificate({
     "type": "######",
     "project_id": "######",
     "private_key_id": "######",
     "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----######-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
     "client_email": "######",
     "client_id": "######",
     "auth_uri": "######",
     "token_uri": "######",
     "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "######",
     "client_x509_cert_url": "######"
})
```